# iPad: How can I simulate a 99% full memory?

Tags: ios, ipad, memory

I'm working on an app that stores data locally on the iPad in the "cache" folder.
With iOS5 the contents in there get deleted randomly when the iPad is getting close to be "full".

How can I simulate an iPad that has for example only 1MB of space left?

Thank you in advance
Oliver

Comment: Surely just remove all the files in cache folder? That's the situation your app will have to deal with, you get no other warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to simulate this that I can think of is to manually place data in `Caches` directory till 99% & see how iOS5 & your app behaves.

One way to do this is to use [**iExplorer**](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/). Install this & open it while your ipad is connected. This will give you a explorer view of all the apps that are installed on your ipad. For example, this is how facebook app looks like.

[image]

Find your App and put data in the `Caches` dir till its close to full. Now run your app from Xcode & see how ios5 & your app handles. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick. The iOS Simulator didn't produce any messages.